# Mongo/No SQL solution to second tier data query?

Tags: mongodb, join, reference, nosql

I have an existing PostgreSQL database, which contains roughly 500,000 entries each of which is essentially a category in a huge tree of categories (each category has different schemas of elements).

I also have a MySQL database, which contains roughly 100,000 documents, each of which can be categories in one or more categories.

I need to be able to search for documents, which match attribute filters which are set in the categories the document is linked to.

As I understand it, I'd have to store all the data relating to all the categories a document links to, in each document, in mongo, and that just seems insane.  How can I make this work?

As an example, imagine a category, which represents a red car, made in 1964, and a document which was written in 1990 about that red car.  I need to be able to search for 1964 and fine the document about the car, as well as the car itself.

Comment: I guess the bigger question is can a mongo data record, contain a reference to another record, or do you have to explicitly set all the contained data as part of every record

Comment: Depending on the mongo driver implementation for the specific language, you can use [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/) to representing a document in another collection (table)

Comment: When your problem is mostly about how to manage cross-references between objects, a graph database could be the tool of choice.

Answer (score 1):

n:m relations in MongoDB can be expressed with arrays of database referencs (DBRef) or arrays of object IDs.

So each document would have a field "categories" which has an array with the IDs or database references of the categories it belongs to.

See this article for further information:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/

An alternative which avoids to perform multiple database queries just to show the names of the categories would be to put the category names in that array instead of the IDs. Then you should also add an index (with the ensureIndex function) to the name field of your category collection for faster lookup (you might want to create a unique index on this field anyway to avoid duplicate category names).

About the data an object has because it belongs to a category, like cars having a manufacturer and a document having a list of other objects mentioned in the document: this data should be put directly into the document of the object. The advantage of a document-oriented database is that not every entity must have the same fields.